# Bokeh plot tag rendering issue

Tags: html, flask, bokeh

I am using the embed .html example given on the bokeh site: http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html. Note I am using bokeh 12.3. The plots are displaying fine but the text is rendering as the exact output from the script function - including '{' and '\n' characters.

scatter function:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import Range1d
from bokeh.embed import components

def scatter():
    # create some data
    x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    y1 = [0, 8, 2, 4, 6, 9, 5, 6, 25, 28, 4, 7]
    x2 = [2, 5, 7, 15, 18, 19, 25, 28, 9, 10, 4]
    y2 = [2, 4, 6, 9, 15, 18, 0, 8, 2, 25, 28]
    x3 = [0, 1, 0, 8, 2, 4, 6, 9, 7, 8, 9]
    y3 = [0, 8, 4, 6, 9, 15, 18, 19, 19, 25, 28]

    # select the tools we want
    TOOLS="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

    # the red and blue graphs will share this data range
    xr1 = Range1d(start=0, end=30)
    yr1 = Range1d(start=0, end=30)

    # only the green will use this data range
    xr2 = Range1d(start=0, end=30)
    yr2 = Range1d(start=0, end=30)

    # build our figures
    p1 = figure(x_range=xr1, y_range=yr1, tools=TOOLS, plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
    p1.scatter(x1, y1, size=12, color="red", alpha=0.5)

    p2 = figure(x_range=xr1, y_range=yr1, tools=TOOLS, plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
    p2.scatter(x2, y2, size=12, color="blue", alpha=0.5)

    p3 = figure(x_range=xr2, y_range=yr2, tools=TOOLS, plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
    p3.scatter(x3, y3, size=12, color="green", alpha=0.5)

    # plots can be a single Bokeh Model, a list/tuple, or even a dictionary
    plots = {'Red': p1, 'Blue': p2, 'Green': p3}

    script, div = components(plots)
    return script, div
```

My flask code is:

```
script, div = scatter()
return self.render_template('bokeh_example.html', script=script, div=div)
```

bokeh_example.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.3.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh*emphasized text*.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.3.min.js"></script>
        {{ script | safe }}
</head>
<body>
    <div class='bokeh'>
        <h1>Scatter Example</h1>
        {{ div | safe }}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The plots display fine but the div text renders as literals:

```
{'Red': '\n    #this text displays instead of just the string 'Red'
\n             #this displays on next line in smaller font
#plot displays fine here
\n             #this text displays after the plot instead of creating a blank line.
```

Any clues?

Comment: I have a (possible) clue, but you've left out the most relevant part, which is what are you actually passing to Bokeh's `components` function. Please update your question with that information.

Comment: @bigreddot I have added the scatter function. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a dictionary of plots to `components`:

```
plots = {'Red': p1, 'Blue': p2, 'Green': p3}

script, div = components(plots)
return script, div
```

This means (per the [documentation](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#components)) that the result is not a single script and a single div. Rather, it's a single script and a dictionary mapping your original names to multiple divs:

```
components({"Red": p1, "Blue": p2, "Green": p3})
#=> (script, {"Red": p1_div, "Blue": p2_div, "Green": p3_div})
```

Right now you are trying to template the dict itself into your HTML. Presumably Jinja just calls `str` on the dict to turn it into a string, and the browser doesn't know what to do with that. You need to template each one of the divs in the dict returned by `components`, individually.

For a suitably updated template, that might look like:

```
script, divs = scatter()   # notice plural: divS
return self.render_template(
    'bokeh_example.html', 
    script=script, 
    div_red=divs['Red'],
    div_blue=divs['Blue'],
    div_green=divs['Green'],
)
```

Or alternatively you might update the template to iterate over `divs` directly using some of Jinja2's capabilities for iterating over template arguments that are collections.